# number of combinations for distributing 20 grades (between 0 and 100) with a a difference of at least 4 between every 2 grades

Tags: combinatorics

im asked to find the number of combinations for distributing 20 grades (between 0 and 100) with a difference of at least 4 between every 2 grades. \
the approach i tried was that if i choose the first number from 0 to 5 (they can increase by 4 or 5 for 19 times) theres: $6\cdot\mathrm{2}^{19}$ combinations. \
and for the numbers from 6 to 24 we have:  $\sum_{i=0}^{19}{19\choose i}$. since 5 is the biggest number from which we can start and only add 5s and by 20th number we reach 100, which is the maximum number. so starting from 6 we have to add less 5s and add 4s (in the 19 increments we have to add 4 somewhere hence the "choose").
but that seems very counter productive and i just realized that i can add 6 or 7 at least one time but i didnt consider them. \
what should i do?

Comment: This is a [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem.  You have $21$ gaps, all but two of which have to be at least $4$, and the gaps must sum to $101-20=81$.

Comment: OK, then I am restoring my original answer !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $21$ gaps or differences ($19$ between the grades and $2$ on the extremes). These gaps must add to give $100$. The first and the last gap can have any length while the other $19$ must have minimum length of $4$.

Let's represent the lengths as $l_1$, $l_2$ ... $l_{21}$. We get the equation

$$l_1 + l_2 + \cdots + l_{21} = 100$$

Again, we are looking for whole number solutions with the condition $l_i \ge 4$ for $2 \le i \le 19$.

If we define $l_i^{'} = l_i - 4$ for $2 \le i \le 19$, we can rewrite the equation above as

$$l_1 + l_2^{'} + l_3^{'} + \cdots + l_{20}^{'} + l_{21} = 24$$

Now each of the variables above can be any whole number. The number of solutions is the answer we are looking for.

All you need to do now is apply the [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) method.

Answer (score 2):

- Make $19$ blocks of four $\boxed{\bullet\circ\circ\circ}$ + a "short" block $\boxed{\bullet}$  with the bullets representing chosen grades
- $101-77 = 24$ balls remain, and we now have $44$ **entities** ($24$ balls + $20$ blocks)
- Place the blocks in $\dbinom{44}{20}$ ways, with the "short" block last amongst blocks

Comment: With a minimum distance of $4$ between grades, it seems there should only be three open circles required in each grouping, not four  (using your notation). For instance if there is a score of $23$, the next higher available score would be $27$, thus skipping $24, 25$, and $26$.

Comment: @paw88789: Thanks,  that is what I had earlier posted , and have rolled back to !

Comment: thank you for your contribution, i reached the same conclusion with distributing of k=24 balls but its to n=21 blocks, and then i used the the ${k+n-1}\choose{k}$ equation

Comment: User1188938: I guess you mean 21 *boxes* ? Nice.